# The MasterPage's behind code is not called

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I just deployed my site in local with IIS manager, but for some reason when I load the page Default.aspx all C#/ASP.NET codes from MasterPage is not loaded. Even though codes from the ContentPlaceHolder do show properly.

For exemple at the place where there is a label, when I look at the page's source code, there is nothing.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="styles/Normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<!-- pour la dynamicite -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tablecloth/tablecloth.js"></script>

</head>
```

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <header>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="carousel_wrapper">
                <div id="carousel" style="height: 260px;">

                    <asp:Literal ID="litCarousel1" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav id="nav-normal">

            <ul style="padding-left: 0px;">
                <li><a href="Default.aspx"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="Nouscontacter.aspx"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Nous Contacter</a></li>
                <li><a href="semaineprochaine.aspx"><i class="icon-facetime-video icon-large"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Semaine Prochaine</a></li>
                <li><a href="macarte57.aspx"><i class="icon-credit-card icon-large"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ma Carte</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <asp:Literal ID="litNouveaute" runat="server" />

    .....
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

                        <div>
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </form

      ......
```

After loading the page, at the place where there is litNouveaute, there is nothing.

Is there a  way to solve this please ?

Comment: Please break your code down to a basic example where you notice this error and show it. Then we might be able to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Label` if you want to see respective HTML markup on your page. `Literal` control is different from `Label` control. As there is not Text assigned to your `Literal` control, you don't see any thing on the page there.

`Literal` control simply emits static text. Unlike `Label`, this cannot be styled. This is a light weight control.

Comment: Well, the labels and literals showed up fine. The issue came from me, I forgot to change the UNC path of the links to my images. And since the MasterPage only display images, I thought the code was not working. Sorry.